# Displaying TinyOWS layer in OpenLayers 4.2

Tags: openlayers, mapserver, tinyows

I went through all the other posts related to this and it got me pretty far, in terms of no errors. But my xml response doesn't contain any geometry points from my source. I'm using the demo from TinyOWS to keep this generic for everyone and since the packaged demo is for openlayers 2.
What I have as my Layer:

```
new ol.layer.Vector({
              source: new ol.source.Vector({
                format: new ol.format.WFS({schemaLocation: "/ms4w/apps/tinyows/schema/"}),
                url: function(extent) {
                   return 'http://localhost/cgi-bin/tinyows.exe?service=wfs&request=DescribeFeatureType&version=1.1.0&typename=tows:frida&srsname=EPSG:3857' 

                }
              })
      })
```

And the response:

```
    <xs:schema xmlns:tows="http://localhost/tinyows/" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" targetNamespace="http://localhost/tinyows/" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.1">
<xs:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml" schemaLocation="http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.1.1/base/gml.xsd"/>
<xs:element name="frida" type="tows:fridaType" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature"/>
<xs:complexType name="fridaType">
<xs:complexContent>
<xs:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="gfshapeid" type="short" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xs:element name="gftypid" type="short" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xs:element name="gfname" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
<xs:simpleType>
<xs:restriction base="string">
<xs:maxLength value="50"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="geom" type="gml:MultiSurfacePropertyType" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

So given that it pulls the layer from the config file and the correct DB columns, I know I'm close. But I don't see what's missing.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find an exact answer, but rather a workaround that solves this (only took an hour of perseverance). Following http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-wfs-getfeature.html as a guideline, I was able to derive this approach:

Layer:

```
new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: wfsSource            //new ol.source.Vector(),
        style: new ol.style.Style({
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)',
            width: 2
          })
        })
      })
```

Then request the data to fill your premade vector layer:

```
var featureRequest = new ol.format.WFS().writeGetFeature({
    srsName: 'EPSG:31467',
    featureNS: 'http://www.mapserver.org/tinyows/',
    featurePrefix: 'tows',
    featureTypes: ['frida'],
    outputFormat: 'application/json'//,
    //filter: ol.format.filter.and(
    //    ol.format.filter.like('name', 'Mississippi*'),
    //    ol.format.filter.equalTo('waterway', 'riverbank')
    //)
  });

  // then post the request and add the received features to a layer
  fetch('http://localhost/cgi-bin/tinyows.exe?service=wfs', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(featureRequest)
  }).then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  }).then(function(json) {
    var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(json);
    wfsSource.addFeatures(features);
    map.getView().fit(wfsSource.getExtent());
  });
```

This is a decent blueprint if you're getting started off with ms4w and need to use a WFS service (being able to select and query your geometries).